# How to start java application after machine reboot?

Tags: boot, java, reboot, tomcat

I'm wondering if there is easier way to start java application (just tomcat server) after machine has been rebooted?

Possible answers:

- Add the application as a service and then add it using `chkconfig <service> on`
- Link in runlevel 5 (e.g `/etc/rc.d/rc5.d` ) script that just starts the application server? And make it executable.
- ?

Edit:
I didn't notice that I put it in runlevel 6 - reboot... ;)

Comment: Runlevel 3 and 5 would be appropriate in most cases. Which tomcat-version, which operating system, which distribution, what version?

Answer (score 2):

When you install the tomcat package, there is already an init script (`/etc/init.d/tomcat7`), which starts tomcat at boot time.

Comment: if using the .tar.gz file from http://tomcat.apache.org (which I prefered), then no /etc/init.d/tomcat exists. the tomcat shipped with distro (CentOS, Fedora) caused too many dependencies to install.

Comment: Sorry, seems I imagined you're using Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: i'm not the OP. :)